# Is it possible to debug in console in a Win32 C++ Application in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

As the question mentions, I am finding it hard to debug and output in a Win32 Windows Program in Visual Studio.
I have used SDL2.0 for OpenGL Projects and SDL window opens with the console as well, so it becomes easy to debug and output anything on the console anytime.
How can I achieve this in Win32 API? Is it anyhow possible to open the console in a Win32 application?

Comment: Er... why don't you use your debugger? Visual Studio allows you to set [trace points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints). When a trace point is hit, you can print arbitrary information to the Output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: There's also `OutputDebugString`.

Comment: @Harry Good point - I have a bit more info on that here: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/c-debug-macros/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the AttachConsole and/or AllocConsole functions of the Windows Console API (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). You can also simply create a Console Application in your IDE, and call your GUI code from that application.